# I can get property from a session attribute, but not from a session map

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, struts2, httpsession, ognl

I am using SSH2. When I try to got an attribute with `<%=session.getAttribute("username") %>`, it was just right.  But when I tried to get the same attribute with `<s:property value="#session.username" />`, I got nothing.

Why? Aren't they the same?

And when I used the `<s:debug>`, I got these:

```
Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session
    at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.initialize(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:167)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.getImplementation(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:215)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer.invoke(JavassistLazyInitializer.java:190)
    at com.bizplus.server.po.Power_$$_javassist_0.toString(Power_$$_javassist_0.java)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2827)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:115)
    at java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(AbstractCollection.java:422)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2827)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:115)
    at java.util.AbstractMap.toString(AbstractMap.java:490)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2827)
    at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:219)
    at freemarker.ext.beans.SimpleMethodModel.exec(SimpleMethodModel.java:130)
    at freemarker.core.MethodCall._getAsTemplateModel(MethodCall.java:93)
    at freemarker.core.Expression.getAsTemplateModel(Expression.java:89)
    at freemarker.core.Expression.getStringValue(Expression.java:93)
    at freemarker.core.StringBuiltins$StringBuiltIn._getAsTemplateModel(StringBuiltins.java:71)
    at freemarker.core.Expression.getAsTemplateModel(Expression.java:89)
    at freemarker.core.Expression.getStringValue(Expression.java:93)
    at freemarker.core.DollarVariable.accept(DollarVariable.java:76)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:210)
    at freemarker.core.IfBlock.accept(IfBlock.java:82)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:210)
    at freemarker.core.MixedContent.accept(MixedContent.java:92)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:210)
    at freemarker.core.IteratorBlock$Context.runLoop(IteratorBlock.java:167)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:417)
    at freemarker.core.IteratorBlock.accept(IteratorBlock.java:102)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:210)
    at freemarker.core.MixedContent.accept(MixedContent.java:92)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:210)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.include(Environment.java:1483)
    at freemarker.core.Include.accept(Include.java:169)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:210)
    at freemarker.core.MixedContent.accept(MixedContent.java:92)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:210)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.process(Environment.java:190)
    at freemarker.template.Template.process(Template.java:237)
    at org.apache.struts2.components.template.FreemarkerTemplateEngine.renderTemplate(FreemarkerTemplateEngine.java:157)
    at org.apache.struts2.components.UIBean.mergeTemplate(UIBean.java:559)
    at org.apache.struts2.components.UIBean.end(UIBean.java:513)
    at org.apache.struts2.views.jsp.ComponentTagSupport.doEndTag(ComponentTagSupport.java:42)
    at org.apache.jsp.test_jsp._jspx_meth_s_005fdebug_005f0(test_jsp.java:133)
    at org.apache.jsp.test_jsp._jspService(test_jsp.java:88)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:393)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet._serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:320)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:266)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.doFilter(FilterDispatcher.java:428)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:198)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:104)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:261)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:581)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

It seems the session in Hibernate. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they are not the same, in the scriptlet you use the http session implicit object, in the struts tag attribute you reference the struts session map object, retrieved via OGNL. You got nothing just because they are different. To use the struts session map you should implement `SessionAware` in the action. So, the servlet config interceptor will inject the session to it, then you could use the session map to put there values, that will be accessible via OGNL.

The example of `SessionAware` implementation:

```
private Map<String, Object> session;

@Override
public void setSession(Map<String, Object> session) {
 this.session = session;
}
```

lazy initialization exception happens because you didn't implement `toString` in the model entities.

See [Accessing application, session, request objects](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WW/Accessing+application,+session,+request+objects)

Comment: They're not the same object (e.g., it's not an `HttpSession`), but OGNL's `#session` should have the same *attributes* as the session scope, since that's where it comes from.

Comment: @DaveNewton You are right, but OGNL's #session should populate those attributes before they become available via OGNL. On the other *and great* side if you put those *attributes* to the OGNL's #session then they always available from `HttpSession`.

Comment: And it does, I can access values in `#session` just fine across multiple versions of S2. I'd be more inclined to think it has something to do with SSH session sharing, because `#session` works just fine under HTTP.

Comment: @DaveNewton May be but OP didn't tell us about it and I guess it's happened because OP affect the http session somehow in his/her code.

Comment: In my action ,I used `ServletActionContext.getRequest().getSession()` to get the `HttpSession`,and uesd `setAttribute()` to add attribute to  it.But it's still not accessible via OGNL.

Comment: And I found that the the `#session` is not accessible if I `redirect` the action to a jsp file in the struts.xml.But it is accessible if I `dispatcher` the action.

Comment: @DaveNewton Thanks.Finally, it works.I think the hibernate lazy initialization exception leads to the hibernate session exception.And then the hibernate session exception leads the exception of session in PageContext.