# Using EL expression but the page can't show the answer correctly

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, el

This is Struts program. I have to make a login page. If  I enter the name `itcast` and password `123` in login page then the page turns to `success.jsp` (I failed in this page ) else  it shows the `error.jsp`.

**`loginaction.java`:**

```
package cn.itcast.action;
import com.opensymphopensymphony.xwork2.ActionContext;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;
public class LoginAction extends ActionSupport {
    private String username; 
    private String password; 
    
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
    
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
    //@Override
    public String execute() throws Exception {
    
        ActionContext context = ActionContext.getContext();
        if ("itcast".equals(username) && "123".equals(password)) {
            
            context.put("username", username);//${username}<br>
            context.put("password", password); //${password} 
            context.put("success", "success");
            return SUCCESS;
        } else {
            
            context.put("error", "error_zdh");
            return ERROR;
        }
    }
}
```

**`struts.xml`:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.3//EN"
    "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.3.dtd">
<struts>
    
    <!-- <constant name="struts.enable.DynamicMethodInvocation" value="false" 
        /> -->
    
    <!-- <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" /> -->
    <package name="default" extends="struts-default">
        <action name="login" class="cn.itcast.action.LoginAction">
            <result name="success" type="redirect">/success.jsp</result>
            <result name="error" type="dispatcher">/error.jsp</result>
        </action>
        
    </package>
</struts>
```

**`login.jsp`:**

```xml
<%@ page language="java" import="java.util.*" pageEncoding="utf-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title>login page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div align="center">login page
        <form action="login" method="post">
            username:<input type="text" name="username" /><br> 
            password:<input
                type="password" name="password" /><br> <input type="submit"
                value="login" />
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**`error.jsp`:**

```xml
<%@ page language="java" import="java.util.*"    pageEncoding="utf-8"%>


<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title>failed page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>
        ${error }<br>
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

**`success.jsp`:**

```xml
<%@ page language="java" import="java.util.*"  pageEncoding="utf-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title>success page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>
        ${success }<br>
    </p>
    <h2>login information</h2>
    username:${username }<br>
     password:${password }<br>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: why don't you debug `execute` as see what is happening?

Comment: Hello! StackOverflow works best if you explain what you've tried, and how the code isn't working as you expected. Thanks for including your code, but it's not clear what your actual question is. Can you be more specific about how you expect the code to work?

Comment: You're redirecting, which means there's a new request, which means there's a new action, which means you no longer have a `username` or `password` anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You misunderstood a `ActionContext` concept. You should distinguish between action context and `ValueStack`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28767130/573032) answer to clarify the problem.

> Every place has its dedicated storage where you can put your objects for later use/retrieve running across some invocation context. Whatever context is running the framework is associated. The context is the way of communicating between scoped objects inside it you can access using Java or other expression language (EL) like OGNL.
>
> In OGNL the action context is the OGNL context, and the value stack is a root.
>
> The framework sets the OGNL context to be our `ActionContext`, and the value stack to be the OGNL root object. (The value stack is a set of several objects, but to OGNL it appears to be a single object.) Along with the value stack, the framework places other objects in the `ActionContext`, including `Map`s representing the application, session, and request contexts. These objects coexist in the `ActionContext`, alongside the value stack (our OGNL root).

Since you redirect to the JSP page the new action is invoked and the new `ActionContext` object is created. It doesn't keep the values from previous context.

What you need is to save the values somewere like a session which you can inject normally by implementing  `SessionAware` or get it directly using API. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17252350/573032) answer to understand which context objects could be used in Struts2 applications.

> To use the Struts session map you should implement `SessionAware` in the action. So, the [servlet config interceptor](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/servlet-config-interceptor.html) will inject the session to it, then you could use the session map to put there values, that will be accessible via OGNL.
>
> The example of `SessionAware` implementation:
>
> ```
> private Map<String, Object> session;
>
> @Override
> public void setSession(Map<String, Object> session) {
>  this.session = session;
> }
> ```
>
> See [Accessing application, session, request objects](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WW/Accessing+application,+session,+request+objects)